# unable to access node:9.1 container in host

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm learning the [getting started guide](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/synopsis.html) offered in Node.js official site, whose code snippet goes as follow.

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Also, I attempt to run that app (stored `app.js` in `${PWD}/guides/getting-started-guide`) in Node's docker container run from the official [node:9.1](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/) image. (The version of docker in use is `Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be`)

```
docker run --rm -p 3000:3000 -u "node" -v ${PWD}/guides/getting-started-guide:/home/node/app -w /home/node/app --name "hello" -it node:9.1 node app.js
```

After the container is up, I see the log `Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/`. And the server responses "Hello World" when queried within the container.

**However, the browser reports `This site can’t be reached` when I try to access it in the host machine with url `http://localhost:3000` or `http://127.0.0.1:3000/`**.

Dying for someone's help~

Comment: Bind to 0.0.0.0 not localhost (127.0.0.1).

Comment: It works!!! Why's that?

Comment: Docker net uses a different interface than localhost, 0.0.0.0 binds all interfaces in the container... its the typical way to bind inside a container.

Comment: To expand on the different interface, A docker container is assigned it's own loopback interface which has the  127.0.0.1/8 range as normal. So `127.0.0.1` in a container refers to a different interface than `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` on the Docker host.